# Overlapping UIViewController subview content despite separate navigation controllers

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a custom UIViewController called ProductDetailViewController, it has lots of subviews and each of the subviews' content is populated by data requested from a remote server.

There are two ways you could end up looking at a product detail view: in one tab of a tab bar controller you can browse to a product and one gets pushed onto the stack of the navigation controller specific to that tab, or in the other tab you can scan a barcode and a ProductDetailViewController gets pushed onto a separate navigation controller within that tab.

The strange thing happening is that if you have a product detail up in one tab, and then bring one up in the other, when you switch back to the first tab you see overlapping duplicate subview content, as in there are two labels/product images/tableviews stacked on one another within the one view.

FYI:

Nothing ever goes wrong with the second instance you push onto a nav controller stack, it's always the first one that this happens to, as if subviews were added into the existing controller as well as the new instance. I don't think there are two entire product detail views being stacked - the view has a solid background color, so it would hide the one beneath. I'm quite certain I'm pushing to separate nav controllers. At first I thought maybe the incoming data was being sent to both controllers, but that wouldn't account for multiple instances of UI elements overlapping.

Has anybody *ever* run into anything like this? It's a first for me for sure, and it's driving me nuts.

Screenshot of overlapping product name label subviews:

[image: overlapping text in product name field]

Comment: This question would benefit greatly from a small screenshot showing what is happening.

Comment: OK done. I can't show much more as this is an app that has been released and isn't my property technically speaking. I built the app originally, it went through QA, and I only just discovered this bug (could be iOS5 specific as far as I know, but will test for that once I have my hands on testing devices).

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you have a lot of [myview addSubview:anothersubview] 
Probably you duplicating subviews when you updating ProductDetailViewController.
Try to insert next code before u start to populate all subviews

```
[[myview subviews] makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Subviews are added to a new instance of productDetailViewComtroller when it is created. This should be an independent process from the other instances. Then again I'm just realizing that there is a delay due to the data being fetched asynchronously it's possible the notification appears the same for all of these controllers and subviews are added as the data arrives. That would likely cause this issue...

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that many of the subviews aren't actually created until data is received, and the application makes use of NSNotificationCenter to determine when data has been returned and what class and function should receive it. I should have mentioned the use of NSNotificationCenter initially, but it hadn't crossed my mind that it could be this type of problem.

I send a string to my API response notification class as an identifier, and by changing that from being the same between all ProductDetailViewControllers, to a unique value by concatenating the requested URL to my string, my problem has been solved.